# view/edit still show in ribbon of DNN after logoff

Tags: dotnetnuke

When I log off a DotNetNuke site, the view/edit options still show in the ribbon up top. Anyone run into this before? I was informed that it's a setting; however, I cannot find this.

Any thoughts? All help is very appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would simply try clearing your browser cache. If it is a setting it means the page is editable to anyone.  Log back in and go to the page settings and make sure 'edit' in the permissions is onel set for 'Administrators' (or whomever you would like to edit it)

Comment: Thanks for your response here too @codemypantsoff. Yep, it was both some permissions with the page and one module I had on the page. So I had to fix two locations. So glad to have this solved! Thank you SO much for your help! :)